# Suggest data-structure for this use case

Tags: java, multithreading, data-structures

Language: Java

I have a fixed pool of threads running, all of who have to ask a question and take user input in the form of (Yes/No) at some point, which would basically decide its further execution. Since I don't want to intermingle the output questions from multiple threads, there will be another task/thread running (single) at fixed rate (Further referred as main thread), which can be used to get the questions and display it to the user. The number of questions asked by the thread may vary and once the question gets a response, it is no longer needed again.

At this point my current implementation uses `LinkedTransferQueue`, which basically allows me to share data between main thread and question thread without having to wait for polling.

I have created a synchronized `ArrayList` of a `Task` class, each of which contains a `LinkedTransferQueue<String>`. The thread creates a new `Task` and adds its question into its queue with `transfer()` method. The main thread picks them up and gets response from user, which is put back to the same queue. The advantage here is that `LinkedTransferQueue` offers a `take()` method that allows me to wait without polling.

Other approaches include using a `volatile shared` variable, whose value is updated by main thread and is constantly being polled by the other thread.

Please suggest if any other data structure is available for such a use case. This is not exactly a producer-consumer problem from what I can understand. Post questions if you have any other concerns.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't understand the reason for broadness. Could you please justify, so that I can take care for future questions? 
I got an answer from Andreas that works for me completely!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the thread to wait for an answer, I'd suggest creating a question object that has the question text, can store the answer, and has a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) for tracking when the answer is available.

```
public final class Question {
    private final String   question;
    private String         answer;
    private CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }
    public String getAnswer() throws InterruptedException {
        this.latch.await();
        return this.answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
        this.latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

Your worker thread can then send that question to the main [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html), and wait for the answer, e.g.

```
public final class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final Queue<Question> queue;
    private final int             delayInSeconds;
    private final String[]        questions;

    public Worker(Queue<Question> queue, int delayInSeconds, String... questions) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.delayInSeconds = delayInSeconds;
        this.questions = questions;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<String> answers = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            for (String question : this.questions) {
                Thread.sleep(this.delayInSeconds * 1000L);
                Question q = new Question(question);
                this.queue.add(q);
                String answer = q.getAnswer();
                answers.add(answer);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException unused) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println(answers);
    }
}
```

The main thread would then use some kind of [`BlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to wait for questions, and to process them one at a time, e.g. like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BlockingQueue<Question> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    Worker w1 = new Worker(queue, 3, "Can you play poker?",
                                     "Can you juggle?",
                                     "Can you summersault?");
    Worker w2 = new Worker(queue, 4, "How old are you?",
                                     "How tall are you?");
    new Thread(w1).start();
    new Thread(w2).start();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Question q = queue.take();
        System.out.println(q.getQuestion());
        String answer = in.nextLine();
        q.setAnswer(answer);
    }
}
```

*Sample output*

```
Can you play poker?
yes
How old are you?
13
Can you juggle?
no
How tall are you?
5 11
Can you summersault?
[13, 5 11]
no
[yes, no, no]
```

Comment: `CountDownLatch` is a much cleaner approach than I took, without having to poll continuously. Great!!